# Display off on last polygon created with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

With this example : 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

I try to create a polygon but I want it to disappear when the polygon is complete.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try to turn off a Draw interaction on `drawend` event

Comment: If you want the polygon to disappear set its geometry (or style) to empty https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-0byve

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the source when creating the interaction:

```
draw = new Draw({
    type: 'Polygon'
  });
```

When no destination source for the drawn features is set, the polygon will just disappear when completed (otherwise it is added to the source).
Listen to drawend event to get the polygon.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I remove the Draw in another function if I let the : 
        source: this.layer.getSource(), ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove the draw interaction after the user geometry draw is complete. Like @Anatoly mention in the comments you can use the `drawend` event to remove the interactions.

Take a look at the example I made for you,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>End Draw Interaction After Draw</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="startDraw">Start Draw</button>
      <button id="endDraw">End Draw</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // vector layer
      var source = new ol.source.Vector();
      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      });
      // map
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
      // buttons
      var startDrawBtn = document.getElementById('startDraw');
      var endDrawBtn = document.getElementById('endDraw');
      endDrawBtn.disabled = true;

      // interaction
      var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type: 'Polygon'
      });
      var snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: source});

      function endInteractions() {
        map.removeInteraction(draw);
        map.removeInteraction(snap);
        startDrawBtn.disabled = false;
        endDrawBtn.disabled = true;
      }

      function startInteractions() {
        startDrawBtn.disabled = true;
        endDrawBtn.disabled = false;
        map.addInteraction(draw);
        map.addInteraction(snap);
        draw.on('drawend', evt => {
          // console.log(evt.feature);
          endInteractions();
        });
      }

      startDrawBtn.addEventListener('click', startInteractions);
      endDrawBtn.addEventListener('click', endInteractions);
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to disappear after the draw end, when the polygon is complete.

Comment: That's what the snippet does .. Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, what is not working as expected?

Comment: I want to remove the Draw object from the source when I have completed the polygon.
With a button wich remove the Draw after it's created